# JSP java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, jsp

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:372)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:292)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:236)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:802)

root cause

java.lang.NullPointerException
java.util.Arrays.mergeSort(Arrays.java:1156)
java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:1080)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:94)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:802)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:324)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:292)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:236)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:802)
```

I am trying to sort a string array and receive the java.lang.NullPointerException.  This is only part of the code but it is the relevant part associated with the error.  I know that when I initialize the string array myRows it sets the values to null.  However, I am checking for nulls and set the values of item_value, period_value, and periodAmt_value to a set value.  When I print out the contents of the array it does contain the set values.  Do not understand why the java.util.Arrays.sort() will not work and why it errors out.  Any help is very much appreciated!!

<%

```
String item_name;
String item_value;

String period_name;
String period_value;

String periodAmt_name;
String periodAmt_value;

String annualAmt_name;
int error_count = 0;
int annualAmt_value = 0;
int totalExp = 0;

String[] myRows = new String[3];


for (int i=0; i < 3; i++)
{
item_name = "item" + i;
item_value = request.getParameter(item_name);

if (item_value == null) 
{
        item_value = "Rent";
}

period_name = "period" + i;
period_value = request.getParameter(period_name);

if (period_value == null) 
{
    period_value = "52";  //default value
}

periodAmt_name = "periodAmt" + i;
periodAmt_value = request.getParameter(periodAmt_name);

if (periodAmt_value == null) 
{
    periodAmt_value = "520";
}


myRows[i] = item_value + "|" + period_value + "|" + periodAmt_value;

out.println(myRows[i]);


java.util.Arrays.sort(myRows);


String text = myRows[i];
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(text, "|");
String[] myFields = new String[st.countTokens()];

out.println("<tr>");

for (int j = 0; j < myFields.length; j++)
{ 
    myFields[j] = st.nextToken();


    if(j==0)
    {
    out.println("<td><input type=text name=" + item_name + " value=" + myFields[j] + "></td>\n");
    }
```

Comment: Can you paste the exact error message (with line numbers ...)?

Comment: Looks like you are calling sort everytime throught the loop, so the first time 2 elements will be null, hence the NullPointerException.

Comment: What is line number of following `java.util.Arrays.sort(myRows);
` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After viewing your exception log I can say with a high degree of certainty that your issue is due to attempting to sort an array containing null elements. Given the flow of your code I stand strongly by my previous recommendation to build your array in entirety, then sort it, then use it to generate your html.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. When you say build your array in its entirety what do you mean exactly?  I am very new to java.

Comment: You need to fully initialize each element in the array with a value. Then sort the array. Then loop over the sorted array and generate your HTML. Currently you are attempting to init the value, sort the array, and generate the html all in the same for loop and that is what is causing your issues.

Comment: Thank you Deadron...I appreciate your input!!